# Evaluating `readLine` in SBT

Tags: scala, io, jvm, monads, read-eval-print-loop

Looking at an `IO Monad` example from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I created an SBT project to test out `IO.scala`:

```
def ReadLine: IO[String] = IO { readLine }
def PrintLine(msg: String): IO[Unit] = IO { println(msg) }

def converter: IO[Unit] = for {
   _ <- PrintLine("Enter a temperature in degrees fahrenheit: ")
   d <- ReadLine.map(_.toDouble)
   _ <- PrintLine(fahrenheitToCelsius(d).toString)
} yield ()
```

But, when I run `console` from SBT to access the above class with REPL, I tried:

```
scala> val echo = Util.ReadLine.flatMap(Util.PrintLine)
echo: common.I01.IO[Unit] = common.I01$IO$$anon$2@71c6b580
```

I'm expecting to be prompted for typing in text (via `readLine`), but I see, as I understand, simply an anonymous function/class.

How can I test out the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `flatMap` on `ReadLine` just produces an `IO[Unit]` value that has not been interpreted. At some point, you have to call `IO#run` (or `IO#unsafePerformIO` in scalaz) to make the side effects happen

To preserve referential transparency, the general idea is to build up an `IO[A]` (where `A` is typically `Unit`) and at the "outermost" part of your program, call `run` on the value -- for example, from the main entry point of the application. That's not always easy/possible though depending on the environment you are running in -- e.g., some form of framework or container.

Because loss of referential transparency is generally considered a pretty serious disadvantage, it is common to defer running of the `IO` value as long as possible. Hence, it is common to say that `IO` is evaluated at the end of the universe.

In this case, the end of the universe is the REPL session, so try calling `echo.run` from the REPL.

Comment: Thank you. When you say `the end of the universe is the REPL session`, could you please elaborate? I've heard universe term before when scanning a Haskell book a few years ago.

Comment: I just cleaned up the terminology a bit and added rationale for the "end of the universe" phrase. Let me know if that's clear.